Posting a link to a Facebook page using using php and curl - returns error
I am trying to use the Graph API to post a link (URL) to a Facebook page, using PHP and
the cURL library. I am able to request a scrape with no issues. But when I try to post
my URL to the page, I get the error:
(#100) Specifying multiple ids with a post method is not supported

I believe that I have the correct scopes to post to my page, per the page Access Token:
email
public_profile
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts

And it's the token for the page I am trying to post to. The URL that I'm pushing through cURL is (URL and MESSAGE are url-encoded):
$request_url = 
      https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE-ID>/?id=<URL-TO-POST>&message=MESSAGE&access_token=<PAGE-TOKEN>;

And I'm using pretty simple curl commands:
$handle = curl_init();

$curl_options = [
                    CURLOPT_URL            => $request_url, 
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => false, 
                    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
                ];
}
curl_setopt_array($handle, $curl_options);
$raw_data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

But the results I get from this call:
[error] => stdClass Object
 (
    [message] => (#100) Specifying multiple ids with a post method is not supported
    [type] => OAuthException
    [code] => 100
    [fbtrace_id] => Av1ZYcuRG0hNE2KZUl94eEv
 )

Am I using the correct URL to post? Are there missing arguments?

The parameter name for the URL is link, not id.

Thank you!  I also had to add "feed":      /feed?link=
